# Objective c animating UIbutton like dock effect on mac os x

Tags: objective-c, ios5, dock, uianimation

I am working on app where I have some list of content shown with some buttons . I need a dock kind of animation when I touches the button , then clicking on the docked button event should be fired. when I touches another button this one should be docked . I have seen the following like 
http://praastitutki2012.wordpress.com/2009/11/23/mac-osx-dock-like-animation-for-iphone/ 
    but , here I need to create a separate view for handling this . But I need this only for some of the buttons only , not for the entire view.
Any suggestions ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't check in details the code you linked, but actually a `UIButton` *is* a `UIView`. You may consider subclassing `UIButton` and implement those methods. This way, animating the whole view means animating the button.

Comment: Hi Saphrosit , Thanks for your quick response. yes , UIButton is also a subclass of UIView . But in that the code written in such a way that our self.view should by kind of that TouchView class and the icons that are at bottom of the view are able to dock . May be I need to check the frames there . Thank you .